# How to omit a single pause when using \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->} command

Tags: beamer, pause

I just started using Texlipse as my Latex environment, and in it's default presentation settings I discovered a wonderful command that lets me omit all the `\pause` commands in my presentation.

By using `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}`, the presentation acts as though a `\pause` command has been inserted between every two bullets, without the actual need to write `\pause` after each item.

My question is, does anyone know how to omit a pause between two consecutive bullets in such a setting? For the 99% of the presentation I prefer the bullets to open up one by one, but in one particular place I would love for the bullets to show up simultaneously.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at [section 9.6.4](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsubsection.9.6.4) and [section 23.1](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsection.23.1) of the `beamer` manual: You can use a dot in the overlay specification (e.g. `<.->`). The dot is replaced by the current value of `beamerpauses` minus one, so if you use `\item<.->`, this item is shown simultaneously with the previous `\item`.

For example, if you have a list with four items and you want to show the second and the third one at the same time, use `\item<.->` for the third item to override the default overlay specification:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item First
    \item Second
    \item<.-> Third
    \item Fourth
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest is to use the overlay specification `[<.->]` in the `itemize` environment. You can check the difference with the following code that I modified the one in the manual page 92 (v.3.12):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Apple
\item Peach
\item Plum
\item Orange
\item Grape
\item Melon
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<.->]
\item Apple 2
\item Peach 2
\item Plum 2
\item Orange 2
\item Grape 2
\item Melon 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```